# firebase snapshot key for children autoids

Tags: swift, firebase

I have the following structure :

```
DATA :
      -kojasd-      <----- child by autoid key name for folder
         property:value
      -kjofs-       <----- child by aytoid key name for folder
         property:value
```

how can I get the key value of the childbyautoid() in a snapshot.children loop ?

here s a bit of code to explain :

```
for items in snap.children {
                    let key = items.key as! String  // DOESN T WORK 

                    let value = items.value!!["property"] as! String


                }
```

in this code, snap refers to DATA

I thought that it would be easy to get this key value, but I m stucked here since a long time, any help ?? :)

sincerely
Yann

Comment: ok, found a solution, I had to pass the snap into a new fdatasnapshot to get its key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people who are using new Xcode 8 beta 3 and swift 3 , many notations have changed and something like the snippet below should give you the children values as String ; basically you would need to do another check and safely upward:

```
        for childSnap in  snapshot.children.allObjects {
            let snap = childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot
            if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let snapVal = snapshotValue[snap.key] as? AnyObject {        
                print("val" , snapVal)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If let's say you have posts you can get it like this.

```
ref.child("posts").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for childSnap in  snapshot.children.allObjects {
        let snap = childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot
        print(snap.key)
        let property = snap.value!["property"] as! NSString
    }
})
```

I know the awnser was already given but I wanted to give some more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent a few moments with that too and although you said this doesn't work for you, I think this is how it should be done:

```
rootRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for item in snapshot.children {
        print(item.key)
    }
})
```

Comment: nope, you have to convert the item into a new FDataSnapshot ( if bot it creates an abiguous value for item.key) as follow     let newitem:FDataSnapshot = item   and then access the newitem.key or value

Answer (score -2):

ok, found a solution, I had to pass the snap into a new fdatasnapshot to get its key

Comment: A little bit more info would be helpful.